# Why I need to specify permit again in the controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, strong-parameters

I am writing an app which has a comment controller, inside the controller,
it has the strong parameter like

```
def comment_params
  params.require(:comment).permit(:text)
end
```

but I found I still need to add permit when I use

`@comment = @post.comments.build(params[:comment].permit(:text))` in the create method or I will receive the error.

I would like to know the reason here. I am using Rails5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why I need to specific permit again in the controller?

Because you didn't use your `comment_params`.

```
@post.comments.build(comment_params)
```

There is no magic, you should use your method.

In this code you didn't use it:

```
@post.comments.build(params[:comment].permit(:text))
```

Comment: This is another question.

Comment: but it is correct when I use  @post.comments.build(params[:comment].permit(:text))

Comment: I dont know, It's hard to diagnose the problem wihout seeing the full code, logs and other related things. Your question is _why I need to specific permit again in the controller?_ and I give to you answer.